# python list referred as true and false in the same time

Tags: python, arraylist

i was coding a simple view in django when the result is always wrong then i noticed the if statement is triggering when it should not i inspected the code to realize it was correct here is the code i tested

```
>>> li = [""]
>>> li == True
False
>>> if li:
...     print("li is true")
...
li is true
>>> li == False
False
>>> li == None
False
>>> li == True
False
```

im so confused?? li == False is false should it not return true?

Comment: The list is not empty, as it contains one item (an empty string, in this case), so as any not empty list, it is truthy (evaluates to `True` in boolean context, as in `if li:`). But it is not *equal* to True, as `True` and your list are completely different things...

Comment: `if li:`, it returns true if list is not empty, false if it's empty

Comment: And it can't be *equal* to `False` either, for the same reason.

Comment: Why do you think ``li == False`` should return ``True``? I think it is correct the way it is right now. I mean can you explain a bit more about your logic why it should be ``True``?

Comment: @Karina since a empty sting in python also returns false so a empty string a a list would also be false but i thought if it returns false then it must be equal to false

Comment: @ahmed mani, oh okay, it makes sense to think that way. But as Thierry said, a list with an empty string is not the same as an empty list.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille that makes sense thank you

Comment: You may want to read about the ["Truthiness of objects in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are assigning to variable `li` a list with one element. Altough, the element is an empty string, it is still an element. Therefore, the list is not empty. If you are not convinced check this `len(li)`; it will be equal to 1.
This is also why the `if li:` statement is True and it actually prints *"li is true"*. Instead try: `if []:` or `if ""` and you will see that it won't print.

Now, `li==True` and `li==False` are both False because it checks if li is True i.e. `li=True` and the same goes for False. Also, it should have been `li=None` so that the statement `li==None` is True.

Answer (score 0):

The result an expression (whether True or False), is determined by how it is expressed as a boolean expression. Python differs from strongly typed languages like Java in that any expression (even a variable reference) can be evaluated to a boolean. Refer to [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

> By default, an object is considered True unless its class defines either a *bool*() method that returns False or a *len*() method that returns zero, when called with the object.

Here are 3 statements to consider:

```
1. li = [""]
2. li == True
3. if li: print("li is true")
```

- Line 1, assign a non-empty list to variable *li*
- Line 2, list instance is not a boolean value so expression is evaluated as False, likewise `li == False` also evaluates to False.
- Line 3, `if li: ...` evaluates same as if bool(li): print... which evaluates to True and prints "li is true".

If evaluate the expression `bool(li)`, the value is True since the list variable is non-empty and *len()* function returns 1. An empty List *len()* returns 0 so will return False.